# Open Source React App Failed to Compile after npm install and npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am getting this error on my window 10 when I try to run this app. This app is on github as open source project. I was trying to contribute to this project but seems like its not compiling. I already have tried changing `react-scripts` to `4.0.1` but still the problem remains. On changing the react-scripts version it is giving me more module not found related errors on npm install.

Please help!

[Link to project repo](https://github.com/Girl-Code-It/Opportunity-Calendar-Frontend)

```
./src/index.js 1:43
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:43)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/Users/Singh's/Desktop/Opportunity-Calendar-Frontend/Opportunity-Calendar-Frontend/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
| $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
rm node_module -r
npm cache verify       
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

Comment: i am getting this error

npm cache clean --force

"npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled." How can I fix this ?